# Problem in Background Mode when sending HTTP POST request

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I'm sending HTTP POST request when getting Firebase  notification from server. I get the notification and want to send request without tapping the notification. Is it possible to send request without tapping the notification?

Answer (score 1):

This may give some idea on fetching content from server without tapping notification.

1. `content-available`: setting content-available only works if the app is in background(inactive, background). if the app is terminated or not even opened, then content-available wont work. apple restricts to sending notification with content-available not more than 5 per hour.

   [https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/CreatingtheNotificationPayload.html](http://Content-available)
2. `mutable-content`: Apple provides `Notification Content Extension` and `Notification Service Extension`. it gives 30 seconds to download your content from server. if server call exceeds 30 seconds, then extension automatically purge the api call, and show the notification to the user. to make use of it, you have to create an extension target.
   [https://medium.com/@prianka.kariat/ios-10-notifications-with-attachments-and-much-more-169a7405ddaf](http://Mutable%20Content)

   NOTE: you should not use mutable content to pull the data from server. why because the notification must be shown to the user. in some cases, developer we will expect to download the data from server without opening the app. mutable-content is not suits for that purpose.

   3.`Background fetch`,
   Background Fetch is automatically initiated by the system at appropriate intervals.

   A very important and cool feature of the Background Fetch is its ability to learn the times that should allow an app to be launched to the background and get updated. Let’s suppose for example that a user uses a news app every morning about 8:30 am (read some news along with some hot coffee). After a few times of usage, the system learns that it’s quite possible that the next time the app will run will be around the same time, so it takes care to let it go live and get updated before the usual launch time (it could be around 8:00 am). That way, when the user opens the app the new and refreshed content is there awaiting for him, and not the opposite! This feature is called usage prediction.
   [Tutorial: https://www.raywenderlich.com/143128/background-modes-tutorial-getting-started (Search for: Testing Background Fetch)](http://Background%20Fetch)

Answer (score 0):

Yes. as you can see in [this Link](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html), if you enable Background Mode and set content-available to 1 in the notification’s payload, the app will call the method application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:, so you can use it to make the request.